# Android Database Normalization

Tags: android, database, sqlite, normalization

Since phones are not nearly as fast as computers, I can see having multiple joins in queries slow down the application.

With redundant data (or non-normalize) it seems like you will have a lot of duplicate data but faster queries.

**So, in android/sqlite, is it better to normalize your database and therefore require more joins in queries or to simply have redundant data but use less joins?**

Any suggestions would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for normalizing the database, Processing power has improved significantly and running queries with joins would be easier than dealing with nightmare of de-normalized schema

Answer (score 0):

Normalization doesn't *always* mean more joins. When the information you need is contained in the foreign key--which happens regularly with natural keys, but *never* happens with id numbers--you don't need a join to get it.

See, for example, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8411739/562459), which deals with stores and their addresses in 5NF with no joins.